# Warning for public method used just in class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, checkstyle

Is there a way to make the IntelliJ Idea inspections or [checkstyle](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/) to give you a warning when a public method is used only in the class where it is defined?

I had the impression that this was possible a while ago, but in the latest weeks I notice that this is not the case (anymore).

Comment: Must be done over the entire project (Analyze, Inspect Code). And then the class could be part of a library that should expose this method. So an expensive hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA, it is one of the inspections. "Declaration access can be weaker".

In the Preferences dialog -> Editor -> Inspections -> Java -> Declaration redundancy -> Declaration access can be weaker.

Comment: You are right, even if this option was set I had some methods where this warning was not triggered, so I think IntelliJ inspections are not very reliable. In our project the warning is not triggered for methods name getTransitions/getType/setType/type... (it doesn't meter the class where they are or the number of parameter or return type)

Comment: I reported the issue here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-233511